# I7 Build I am conflicted

Tags: motherboard, memory, ssd, hard-disk, processor

I am looking for some recommendations for my new I7 Build.

**What I use it for**

Day to day business work

**Applications open at once**

- Adobe Illustator
- Firefox (11 Tabs)
- Chrome (5-10 Windows / 10-20 Tabs in each)
- Skype
- QQ Messenger
- Jitsi (VOIP Dialer)
- Outlook
- Notepad ++
- Windows Photo Viewer (typically 3-10 images)
- Amazon S3 Viewer
- Excel (3-10 Docs)
- Word (1-2 Docs)
- Open VPN
- One Drive
- FileZila
- BitVise
- Windows explorer (3-5 Windows)
- Calculator (thought i would throw this in to be accurate)

**Occasionally Open**

- Edge
- Internet Explorer
- Acrobat
- Adobe Bridge (this could be more frequent in the future)

**Visualization Information**

- I will be using 3 Monitors at 1920x1080 Resolution but I will be wanting to add a 4th in the very near future

**Overclocking**

- Looking for recommendations here

**Budget**

Originally I was planning on doing this build under 1000 but now I am thinking i am going to end up in the 1500 range.  I have money to burn but I don't like burning it.

**What I know I want**

I7 Processor

32GB Ram (Dual Channel if I go 6700 quad if i go 6800)

500GB SSD or NVMI

PLAIN Case (its a business not an art show)

GPU that can handle my quad monitor setup

USB Type C Port on MB (Unless someone has a reason why not)

**Current Conflicts**

I7-6700K vs I7-6800K

Air Cooled vs Water Cooled

DDR4 3000 vs Faster

Sata SSD vs NVMi SSD

**Areas where I have not a clue**

MotherBoard

GPU

PSU (I do know how to add so my plan was to take everything add up the wattage and give my self about 20% head room)

Comment: Have you researched into the system requirements for the software you plan to use?  Have you done any research into what hardware configuration will fit into your budget?   Try and put together a configuration for people to make suggestions on, we cannot do full system designs for you.

Comment: Unfortunately, we do not do build reviews here. If you would like to see how to ask questions about builds, please check out [these](http://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aquestion+user%3A60+college) questions. Please try to keep it to one component per question.

Comment: I'm closing this question because we do not allow build requests (or reviews) on this site, as Cfinley stated. They elicit far too many largely opinion-based answers. Please see [these](http://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aquestion+user%3A60+college) questions for examples of how you could split this question up so it's allowed. Thanks!

Comment: Have you considered an i9? or maybe an i7 8th gen?

Comment: @Tgamer I finished this project in 2016 but I went with the 6800K which I can tell you I am much happier with than another machine almost identical with a 7700k.  The handling of large numbers of applications open in windows is handled much better on the 6800.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay did not get much response here so I did 5 more days of research and this is what I came to.

**Processor:** i7-6800K

- Reason: I decided due to the amount of multi-tasking I do that the extra cores were too enticing to pass up.
- Vendor: Microcenter - $329.00
- Note: There was a sale so the processor was only $10 more

**Cooler:** Corsair Hydro H100i V2

- Reason: I figured I would be tempted to overclock the 6700K so I justified the cost on both processors (another reason why I went with the 6800K)
- Vendor: Amazon - $99.99 (on sale)

**Motherboard:** ASRock X99 Taichi

- Reasons: True quad channel MB, 8 DIM slots, dual NICs, builtiin Wi-Fi, dual M.2 ports, USB Type-C port, well-spaced PCIe ports
- Vendor: NewEgg - $199.99 - $20 Rebate + $0.99 Shipping = $181.98 (I could have saved another $30 with the combo at Microcenter but they did not have this board)

**Ram:** GSkill Ripjaws 4 DDR4 4x8GB 3000MHZ

- Reasons: Ripjaws 4 was built specifically for Quad Channel vs Ripjaws 5 Etc / Good Value
- Vendor: NewEgg $199.99 - $20 Promo Code = $179.99

**Video Card:** Gigabyte GeForce GTX1060 GV-N1060G1GAMING-6GD

- Reasons: Do you know how hard it is to find and verify that a video card will actually support 4 monitors? I do now. Besides that it seems like a decent card for my purposes.
- Vendor: Amazon - $274.99 - $20 rebate = $254.99

**Storage:** Plextor M8PE M.2 2280 512GB NVMe

- Reasons: Super fast drive, almost as fast as Samsung 960 Pro for a lot less money. Samsung 960 Evo is not out yet (this would have been my preference).
- Side note: I really wanted the AIC version of this drive but I goofed around and it sold out. Other vendors were too expensive and now I will have to get heatsink recommendations for this from this forum
- Vendor: Newegg $249.99 - $25 Promo code = $224.99

**PSU:** Corsair CS Series CS750M 750W Gold

- Reasons: Plenty of power and room for extra stuff, gold rated, semi-modular, ON SALE
- Vendor: Amazon - $79.99

**Case:** Undecided, but I am going to go down to Frys and get something locally.

Total Cost: $1350.93

This ended up being a very painful experience but I do feel like I got a really good system out of this. I really struggled with another issue as well and that is the fact that the i7-7700K Is coming out in a month and smashes this processor in benchmarks. In the end when that happens most likely I will give this computer to my wife and daughter and put myself through this misery again.

I hope this helps someone if they have this same struggle.

Comment: Switched to Samsung 960 Evo Specs are better and the price is the same - the promo code that was received.  NewEgg was really late with the shipment and the item showed up damaged so at this point by the time I get the replacement Amazon will have me the EVO and a 20% (Based on specs) performance boost.

Answer (score -3):

I7-6700K vs I7-6800K     =  6700k your turbo boost will be higher and I have experience with both 6700k ran a lot cooler.

Air Cooled vs Water Cooled  = In my professional opinon with what you want to do i would recommend liquid cooling

DDR4 3000 vs Faster = cost effective i say DDR4 3000

Sata SSD vs NVMi SSD= SATA SSD

1600 WATT Power Supply  Platinum Rated

GIGABYTE G1 Gaming GA-Z170X-Gaming G1 (rev. 1.0) LGA 1151 Intel Z170 HDMI SATA 6Gb/s USB 3.1 USB 3.0 Extended ATX Intel Motherboard

Inno3D NVIDIA Geforce GTX 970 4GB Overclocked Video Card HD1080,4K,4 monitors x3

My opinion if you want me to do a full spec for you email me @ info.ethanohara@gmail.com

Comment: Care to share some light on your decisions? I find your choice of a vastly overrated power supply (of what model?) and a last generation graphics card mystifying.